# Generating XML with cdata using Ox?

Tags: ruby, xml, xml-parsing, nokogiri

I need to generate XML using [ox](https://github.com/ohler55/ox) but didn't get much help from the documentation.  I need to generate XML like this:

```
<Jobpostings>
  <Postings>
    <Posting>
      <JobTitle><cdata>Programmer Analyst 3-IT</cdata></JobTitle>
      <Location><cdata>Romania,Bucharest...</cdata></Location>
      <CountryCode><cdata>US</cdata>   </CountryCode>
      <JobDescription><cdata>class technology to develop.</cdata></JobDescription>             
    </Posting>     
  </Postings>
</jobpostings>
```

I have the data inside the tags as strings in variables like this:

```
jobtitle = "Programmer Analyst 3-IT" and so on...
```

I am currently using Nokogiri to generate XML but I need to work on large data, and, for the performance sake I am moving to Ox.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: The performance of Ox [is impressive](http://www.ohler.com/dev/xml_with_ruby/xml_with_ruby.html).

Comment: Ox is very performant, but I've noticed it is missing some of the features of heavier weight libraries like Nokogiri. This might have been purposeful by design though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's pretty simple, you just initialize new elements and append them to other elements. Unfortunately there isn't an XML builder in the Ox library though... Here's an example:

```
require 'ox'
include Ox

source = Document.new

jobpostings = Element.new('Jobpostings')
source << jobpostings

postings = Element.new('Postings')
jobpostings << postings

posting = Element.new('Posting')
postings << posting

jobtitle = Element.new('JobTitle')
posting << jobtitle
jobtitle << CData.new('Programmer Analyst 3-IT')

location = Element.new('Location')
posting << location
location << CData.new('Romania,Bucharest...')

countrycode = Element.new('CountryCode')
posting << countrycode
countrycode << CData.new('US')
countrycode << '   '

jobdescription = Element.new('JobDescription')
posting << jobdescription
jobdescription << CData.new('class technology to develop.')

puts dump(source)
```

Returns:

```
<Jobpostings>
  <Postings>
    <Posting>
      <JobTitle>
        <![CDATA[Programmer Analyst 3-IT]]>
      </JobTitle>
      <Location>
        <![CDATA[Romania,Bucharest...]]>
      </Location>
      <CountryCode>
        <![CDATA[US]]>   </CountryCode>
      <JobDescription>
        <![CDATA[class technology to develop.]]>
      </JobDescription>
    </Posting>
  </Postings>
</Jobpostings>
```